# Java Observer / Observable equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, java

I'm toying a bit with `IObservable` and `IObserver` in C# after using it's Java equivalent. However I'm not entirely sure how to use it correctly. I've Googled this, but the results are either too problem-specific or way too unnecessarily complex.

This is my very basic Java code :

```
public class SomeController extends Observable{

    public void doSomething()
    {
        //dostuff
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

}

public class SomeView implements Observer{

    private SomeController controller;

    public SomeView (SomeController ctrl)
    {
        this.controller= ctrl;
        ctrl.addObserver(this);
    }

    public void update (Observable o,Object arg)
    {
        if (o==controller)
        System.out.println("Update detected");
    }

}
```

Right, so how do I do the very exact same thing in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# has built-in support for the observer pattern, in the form of events. I think this is what you're looking for.

```
public delegate void UpdatedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public class SomeController {

    public event UpdatedEventHandler Updated;

    protected virtual void OnUpdated(EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (Updated != null)
        {
            this.Updated(this, e);
        }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do stuff

        this.OnUpdated(new EventArgs());
    }
}

public class SomeView implements Observer{

    private SomeController controller;

    public SomeView(SomeController ctrl)
    {
        this.controller = ctrl;
        ctrl.Changed += this.OnControllerChanged;
    }

    private void OnControllerChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == this.controller)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Update detected");
        }
    }
}
```

In C#, `IObservable` and `IObserver` primarily appear as part of [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/gg577609.aspx), to represent asynchronous observable sequences and event listeners.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be doing what I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

C# has events a delegates.

Check out http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000040.html

But as Observable is just an interface you could make a replica of the java-way if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about INotifyPropertyChanged implementation?
Here's an exemple :
[INotifyPropertyChanged exemple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)
In this case, you should probably use MVVM patern instead of MVC : 
[Mvvm post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)
Hope this helps